# show that $3^n< n!$ if n is an integer greater than 6

Tags: inequality

This prove requires mathematical induction
Basis step: $n=7$

which is indeed true since $3^7\lt 7!$
where $3^7=2187$, $7!=5040$, and $2187< 5040$ hence p(7) is true.

Inductive step: 
Assume: $3^k< k!$, then this where I need hints to continue, however correct me if I am wrong somewhere above.

Comment: I had edited the question and this should be the correct question above.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that $3^n \leq n!$ for $n>6$.

Base case:
$$
3^7 = 2187 < 7! = 5040
$$
Inductive step:

We want to show that given $3^n < n!$ then $3^{n+1} < (n+1)!$
$$
 3^{n+1} < (n+1)!
$$
$$
3 \cdot3^n < (n+1) n!
$$
We know that $3^n< n!$, so we just need to show that $3 < (n+1)$, which is always true since $n>6$.

Comment: do we need to show that 3<(n+1) or 3<(n+1)!?

Comment: Only that $3 <n+1$ since those are the new factors on each side for the $n+1$ case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n = 3^n$ and $b_n = n!$

If $a_n \leq b_n$, then $a_{n+1} = 3 \cdot a_n \leq b_{n+1} = (n+1) \cdot b_n$; after all, $n>6$ implies $n+1 > 3$.

Comment: please see the edited question and specifically answer. Thanks.

Comment: What I answered is how to proceed on the inductive step. You've shown that, for $n=7$, $a_n \leq b_n$. You can follow through with the reasoning presented above.

Answer (score 0):

From
$(1+\frac1{n})^n
< e
<(1+\frac1{n})^{n+1}
$
(proved here often),
we can show by induction that
$(n/e)^n
< n!
< (n/e)^{n+1}
$.

Therefore,
if $n/e > k$,
or
$n > ek$,
$n! > k^n$.

If $k=3$,
this gives
$n! > 3^n$
for
$n>3e 
=8.1...
$.

Checking for
$n=7, 8$
can be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

show 3^n<n! is true for all n great or equal to 7
step 1 show for n=7, 3^7<7!,2187<5400  so it is true
step 2 show for n=k  3^k<k! is true for n greater or equal to 7
step 3 show for n=k+1 3^(k+1)<(k+1)! is our claim
now  3^(k+1)=3.3^k<3.k!  since 3^k<k!
then 3.3^k<3.k!<(k+1)k!  since 3<k for k great or equal to 7
so,3.3^k=3^(k+1)<(k+1)k!=(k+1)!  is true for all n is great or equal to 7

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What's the point of posting with the same solution as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1791014/446262)?